# how to set the php json encode multi dimensional array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

Good morning,

I have a very specific example that I am trying to implement. The goal is to get the following JSON end result.

```
{
    merchantId :"123456",
    tenderType :"Card",
    amount :"0.02",
    account :
    {
        number : "4111",
        expiryMonth : "02",
        expiryyear : "2016",
        cvv : "019",
        avsZip : "30014",
        avsStreet: "2001 Main"
    }
}
```

I am familiar with json_encode and I have can get this done for the 1st 3 parameters with the following code:

```
json_encode(
        array(
                "merchantId" => "123456",
                "tenderType" => "Card",
                "amount" => "0.02"
              )
    }
```

but the 4th parameter (account) is getting me stuck.  Can anybody explain to me how to incorporate the 4th parameter that is itself an array.

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be a nested associative array:

```
json_encode(
    array(
        "merchantId" => "123456",
        "tenderType" => "Card",
        "amount" => "0.02",
        "account" => array(
            "number" => "4111",
            "expiryMonth" => "02",
            "expiryyear" => "2016",
            "cvv " => "019",
            "avsZip" => "30014",
            "avsStreet" => "2001 Main" 
        )  
    )
)
```